# Subscript in geom_label

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, subscript

I am trying to make a plot of growing degree day data with a label indicating the current number of growing degree days. I want the label to read:
999 GDD<sub>50F</sub>
However parse does not seem to work with the code I have:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

data.frame(x=sort(runif(100,0,100)),
           y=sort(runif(100,0,100)))%>%
  ggplot(aes(x=x, y=y))+
    geom_line()+
    geom_label(aes(x=max(x), y=max(y),
                   label=paste0(round(max(y))," GDD[50F]")),
               hjust=1, parse=T)
```

I feel like `bquote()` or `expression()` might work but I can't figure out how to get the maximum value as part of the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way using `geom_richtext` from `ggtext`.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggtext)

data.frame(x=sort(runif(100,0,100)),
           y=sort(runif(100,0,100))) %>%
ggplot(aes(x=x,y=y))+
  geom_line()+
  geom_richtext(aes(x=max(x),
                 y=max(y),
                 label=paste(round(max(y)), "GDD<sub>50F</sub>")),
             hjust=1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `backticks` here.

```
df <- data.frame(x=sort(runif(100,0,100)),
           y=sort(runif(100,0,100)))
label <- paste0("`",round(max(df$y))," GDD`[`50F`]")

ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y))+
   geom_line()+
   annotate(geom="label", x=max(df$x), y=max(df$y), label=label, parse = TRUE)
```

[image: output]

Comment: Please note that your `geom_label()` still works - instead of `annotate()`